# unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "fonts/Signatra.ttf"

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Can anyone can help me with this problem?

> ```
> Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml:
> "fonts/Signatra.ttf".
>
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * Where: Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
>
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1
> ```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the related lines of your pubspec. Have you add this font in your asset directory?

Answer (score 1):

Please check on the following pointers and fix your path in pubspec.ymal accordingly:

The assets folder should be in the root path (/). If you want to keep it in the lib folder, put lib in front of assets like this:

```
`lib/assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf`
```

If you want to keep it in the asset folder:

```
`assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf`
```

PS: please check the name of file and the name which you are entering in pubspec.ymal also.